# Could not initialize class com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.taintanalysis.TaintMethodSummary

Tags: java, android, android-studio, findbugs, find-sec-bugs

I'm using FindBugs-IDEA 1.0.0 with FindBugs 3.0.1. My Android studio version is 2.1.2.

I'm only using FindBugs to analyse 1 single Java file (a fragment) if that matters

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.taintanalysis.TaintMethodSummary
    at com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.taintanalysis.TaintMethodSummaryMap.putFromLine(TaintMethodSummaryMap.java:67)
    at com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.taintanalysis.TaintMethodSummaryMap.load(TaintMethodSummaryMap.java:47)
    at com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.taintanalysis.TaintDataflowEngine.loadMethodSummaries(TaintDataflowEngine.java:82)
    at com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.taintanalysis.TaintDataflowEngine.<init>(TaintDataflowEngine.java:73)
    at com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.taintanalysis.EngineRegistrar.registerAnalysisEngines(EngineRegistrar.java:32)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.registerPluginAnalysisEngines(FindBugs2.java:633)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.createAnalysisCache(FindBugs2.java:594)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:211)
    at org.twodividedbyzero.idea.findbugs.core.FindBugsStarter.executeImpl(FindBugsStarter.java:354)
    at org.twodividedbyzero.idea.findbugs.core.FindBugsStarter.asyncStartImpl(FindBugsStarter.java:245)
    at org.twodividedbyzero.idea.findbugs.core.FindBugsStarter.asyncStart(FindBugsStarter.java:218)
    at org.twodividedbyzero.idea.findbugs.core.FindBugsStarter.access$300(FindBugsStarter.java:74)
    at org.twodividedbyzero.idea.findbugs.core.FindBugsStarter$3.run(FindBugsStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to test:

- Load the latest version of **Find Security Bugs 1.4.6** (which is not the one bundle with FindBugs-IDEA at the moment) http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/download.htm

The FindBugs plugins can be configured in **Other Settings** **>** **FindBugs-IDEA**

If you keep getting the error, you can [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/issues).